# laravel db query paginate get row ids in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello I'm using db query in my controller

```
$query = DB::table('users');
$records = $query->paginate(50);
```

in view I access the records as

```
@foreach ($records as $row)
 <tr>
   <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
   <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
 </tr>  
@endforeach
```

now the name and email are all correct except for the id it only generates 1

example:

```
-------------------------
1 | name1 | email1
-------------------------
1 | name2 | name2
------------------------
1 | name3 | name 3
```

i don't know why it's only showing up 1 in the id when the var_dump(DB::getQueryLog());
shows the correct ids 1, 2, 3

**note: this is a large database around 500k records it could show 200231 as the ID**

I'm using Laravel Framework 5.8.35

Comment: did you try clear cache?

Comment: I followed this https://tecadmin.net/clear-cache-laravel-5/ still problem persists

Comment: Can you var_dump($records) and show the result?

Comment: @Andreidev You can try to print records `dd($records )` in the controller. Check id return correct. Also, check your blade file call the correct variable.

Comment: yes the records is correct using var_dump and dd I forgot to mention there are left joins there so what I did I just setup an alias on the user id thank you

Comment: @Andreidev So put all the information in the question with left join.

Answer (score 0):

In your blade try this

```
@foreach ($records as $key => $row)
 <tr>
   <td>{{ $records[$key]->id }}</td>
   <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
 </tr>  
@endforeach
```

See if it solves your problem